# How can I find all paths in javascript file with regex in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

Sample Javascript (content):

```js
t.appendChild(u),t}},{10:10}],16:[function(e,t,r){e(10);t.exports=function(e){var t=document.createDocumentFragment(),r=document.createElement("img");r.setAttribute("alt",e.empty),r.id="trk_recaptcha",r.setAttribute("src","/cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/js/re/transparent.gif?ray="+e.ray),t.appendChild(r);var n=document.createTextNode(" ");t.appendChild(n);var a=document.createElement("input");a.id="id",a.setAttribute("name","id"),a.setAttribute("type","hidden"),a.setAttribute("value",e.ray),t.appendChild(a);var i=document.createTextNode(" ");t.appendChild(i);

t.appendChild(u),t}},{10:10}],16:[function(e,t,r){e(10);t.exports=function(e){var t=document.createDocumentFragment(),r=document.createElement("img");r.setAttribute("alt",e.empty),r.id="trk_recaptcha",r.setAttribute("sdfdsfsfds",'/test/path'),t.appendChild(r);var n=document.createTextNode(" ");t.appendChild(n);var a=document.createElement("input");a.id="id",a.setAttribute("name","id"),a.setAttribute("type","hidden"),a.setAttribute("value",e.ray),t.appendChild(a);var i=document.createTextNode(" ");t.appendChild(i);
```

```
regex = ""
endpoints = re.findall(regex, content)
```

Output I want:

```
> /cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/js/re/transparent.gif?ray=
> /test/path
```

I want to find all fields starting with "/ and '/ with regex. I've tried many url regexes but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```py
import re

txt = ... #your code
pat = r"(\"|\')(\/.*?)\1"

for el in re.findall(pat, txt):
    print(el[1])
```

each `el` will be match of pattern starting with single, or double quote. Then minimal number of characters, then the same character as at the beginning (same type of quote).

`.*` stands for whatever number of any characters, following `?` makes it non-greedy i.e. provides minimal characters match. Then `\1` refers to first group, so it will match whatever type of quote was matched at the beginning. Then by specifying `el[1]` we return second group matched i.e. whatever was matched within quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
regex = r"""["']\/[^"']*"""
```

Note that you will need to trim the first character from the match. This also assumes that there are no quotation marks in the path.

Comment: Can you please rearrange your code according to the code sample above? I am getting a "Missing closing quote" error.

Comment: How about this?